# Error setting up Apollo server - Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '() => DataSources<object>'

Tags: typescript, apollo, apollo-server

I know it is typescript related. The function dataSources below is expecting a return of a certain type and I am not sure how to implement in this situation

Here is the code -

```
const dataSources = () => {
    quizzessApi: new QuizzessDataSource();
}

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers, dataSources  });
export default server.createHandler();
```

This is the error I see on vscode -

[image: typescript error message]

Updated with the QuizzesDataSource class -

```
import { DataSource } from "apollo-datasource";

export interface quizzessInterface {
    id: string;
    question: string;
    correctAnswer: string;
}


export class QuizzessDataSource extends DataSource {
    getQuizzess = async (parent, args) => {
        const query = `SELECT * FROM c`;
        const results = await this.findManyByQuery(
          {
            query,
          },
        );
        return results.resources;
    };
}
```

Comment: Please include the code for your `QuizzesDataSource` class

Comment: @MichelFloyd QuizzesDataSource class has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're not actually returning anything from your `dataSources` because js is interpreting the curly braces as the body of a function instead of an object (although it should then have returned an `unexpected token` error).

Either:

```
const dataSources = () => {
    return { quizzessApi: new QuizzessDataSource() };
};
```

or

```
const dataSources = () => ({ quizzessApi: new QuizzessDataSource() });
```

Comment: Doesn't it complain about the `dataSources` being of a wrong type (as if it inferred its type incorrectly)?

Comment: Would you add a small note on why their original syntax was wrong? (I +1d already anyway)